# Identity provider ASP.NET Facebook Authentication not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm using Microsoft's Identity framework to use external logins. All the others worked except for Facebook. When I'm using Facebook it let's me login but doesn't ask for permission and instantly returns me to the login page, without being authorized.

The callback url is http://localhost:14613/signin-facebook/

This is my external login authentication code (With the ID and Secret Blanked):

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
               appId: "XXXXXXX",
               appSecret: "XXXXXXX"
            );
```

The expected result it that it would redirect me to: localhost/Account/ExternalLoginSucceeded

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar issue, though resolved while updating following nuget packages:

1. Microsoft.Owin to version 3.1.0
2. Microsoft.Owin.Security to version 3.1.0
3. Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies to version 3.1.0
4. Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth to version 3.1.0
5. Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook to version 3.1.0

Startup.cs code is:

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
     AppId = "xxxxxx",
     AppSecret = "xxxxxx", 
     Scope = { "email" },
     Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
      {
         OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
           {
               context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:accesstoken", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"));
               return Task.FromResult(0);
           }
      }
}; 
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

And my facebook graph api version is 2.8

Comment: Fixed my issue - thanks! After looking into the problem a bit more, here's the reason it stopped working: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you mast have Owin version**:

> **3.1.0**

**installed with NuGet**

I found some kind of similar solution, I changed it and update it for other functionality like get facebook user likes and is working great

**Here is code (paste in Startup.Auth):**

```
        var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId =     "-----copy from your facebook app-----",
            AppSecret = "-----copy from your facebook app-----",
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            },

            //BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
            //UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,location"
        };
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        //facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_likes");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```